# SQL query, select top result or bottom result depending on if row exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select rows:

One for each distinct centerid and studentid
The column status is not 'D' and the oldest one (I use autoincremented `id`).
If no such row exists, find the newest column with createdDate today and status='D'.
No row for that centerid, studentid, if no such row exists.

Below is the query I'm currently using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM DailyJournals as DJ
WHERE IFNULL(
        (SELECT id FROM DailyJournals AS x WHERE DJ.studentid = x.studentid AND DJ.centerid = x.centerid
          AND NOT status = 'D' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
        (SELECT id FROM DailyJournals AS x WHERE DJ.studentid = x.studentid AND DJ.centerid = x.centerid
          AND createdDate = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
      ) = DJ.id;
```

Trying to find the best way to add indexes and structure the query and DB to keep this reasonably optimized while keeping it simple.  Load is very small for now, and the table gets pruned, so performance isn't currently an issue.

MariaDB 10.4
centerid and studentid are 3 character alphanumeric strings.  id is autoincremented indexed primary key.  createdDate is a date string for when the row was created.

Some additional information:

> (There are only a few possible values for column status and it's a 2
>   character string)   which I've set up an indexed virtual boolean
>   column for (done=0 or done=1)

```sql
alter table DailyJournals add column `done` bool as (status='D');
create index done on DailyJournals(done);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `row_number()`:

```
select dj.*
from (select dj.*,
             row_number() over (partition by centerid, studentid
                                order by (status <> 'D') desc,
                                         (case when status <> 'D' then id end) desc,
                                         id asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from dailyjournals dj
     ) dj
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

From a performance perspective, probably the best you can do is a computed column with an index.

```
alter table DailyJournals
    add column magic_d_id int as 
        (status = 'D' then id else - id end);

create index dailyjournals_magic_d_id on DailyJournals(centerid, dataid, magic_d_id);
```

You can try `row_number()`:

```
row_number() over (partition by centerid, studentid order by magic_d_id)
```

I'm not sure if that will use the index.  You can also use:

```
select dj.*
from dailyjournals dj
where dj.magic_d_id = (select dj2.magic_d_id
                       from dailyjournals dj2
                       where dj2.centerid = dj.centerid and
                             dj2.studentid = dj.studentid and
                       order by dj2.magic_d_id
                       limit 1
                      );
```

This assumes that `id` is an integer and never negative.

Comment: It appears to still be doing a full table scan both ways.  I've added index for centerid, studentid, and switched to using the indexed "done" boolean to no avail.  This works, but is it going to do any better than the query I put in the original question, which does one full table scan?

Comment: so it appears that generated columns don't work with autoincremented columns https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13320.  is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use createdDate instead?

Comment: @user120242 . . . You can use the same idea with `to_seconds(createdDate)`, I think.

Comment: Helped me to think of some possible optimizations, but none very satisfying.  Seems like the biggest blocker is the `createdDate=NOW()` requirement.  Feels a bit like premature optimization now, since the table size probably won't ever be a problem, and it's simpler to understand as-is.  I'll just accept this as answer.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for improved db structure or query design here?  Whether it's just for better queries, or for organization and cleaner code?  Let's say I need to branch this table's query out for real-time access in the future, what should I pay attention to?